# adding link to each elements to an array containing png file (php)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array containing different images file they only contains images file name.I want to add an url before each filename in that array.
For example :

### The main array

```
    $imgUrls = array(
       'ptSignature' => '5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
       'pSignature' => '5668694f80aa55.79055562.png',
       'witness1Signature' => '5668695875c6e5.03917128.png',
       'witness2Signature' => '5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
    );
```

I want them like this :

```
$imgUrls = array(
       'ptSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
       'pSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668694f80aa55.79055562.png',
       'witness1Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695875c6e5.03917128.png',
       'witness2Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
    );
```

How i can manage that?

Comment: Take a look at `array_walk()`

Comment: @Rizier123 Why use array_walk vs `foreach($imgUrls as $key=>$val) { $imgUrls[$key] = 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=' . $val; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
  foreach($imgUrls as $key=>$value) 
     { $imgUrls[$key] = 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=' . $value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$imgUrls = array(
       'ptSignature' => '5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
       'pSignature' => '5668694f80aa55.79055562.png',
       'witness1Signature' => '5668695875c6e5.03917128.png',
       'witness2Signature' => '5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
    );

$imgUrls = array_map(function($el) {
    return 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=' . $el;
}, $imgUrls);

var_dump($imgUrls);
```